# Is it possible to check whether a value is in the list of items in a single Oracle Decode Function?

Tags: oracle, decode

I would like to know that if I can compare a value with a list of items in an decode function. Basically I want to know that if is it possible to make a decode statement's '*search*' value a list. For example,

```
decode(task_id, (1,2,3), 3 * task_time)
```

This piece of code won't compile though. Is this the only option for this case then (without using *case-when*) or are there alternative ways of doing this?

```
decode(task_id, 1, 3 * task_time,
                2, 3 * task_time,
                3, 3 * task_time)
```

I am using Oracle 10gR2. Any help is much appreciated.

Comment: Though I understand your reluctance to use a `case` statement - I don't think they look as clean - they are much more powerful than decode and can be used in more places and are transferable cross RDBMS. @Codo's answer is the one you need.

Comment: tough question. But why you don't use CASE? Do you have a benefit from decode?

Comment: This question is just the result of my personal interest. Furthermore I would like to test decode function vs case clause after I fill the related tables with large data.

Comment: You are on Oracle 10g.  Why do you want to try to make DECODE() do something it cannot do rather than use CASE() which can do it?

Comment: OK. Most of the answers & comments proved that using case clause in my case is the ideal solution approach. So, I'm gonna go with @Codo's answer here. Thank you all, for your responses.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If a single list of values is sufficient, you can turn it into a `CASE` and `IN` clause:

```
case when task_id in (1, 2, 3) then 3 * task_time else null end
```

Comment: Like I said in the question, I wonder if it's possible with decode function without using case - when clause.

Answer (score 1):

I don't think its possible to use a list with decode in this way.  Per the docs:

> DECODE compares expr to each search value one by one. If expr is equal
>   to a search, then Oracle Database returns the corresponding result. If
>   no match is found, then Oracle returns default

So task_id is compared with a search value one by one.  If search value was a list, you couldn't compare with a single value.

Answer (score 1):

I found a solution :)

```
select 
    decode(
          task_id, 
          (select task_id from dual where task_id in (1,2,3)), 
          3*task_time)
```

Comment: or `decode(task_id,decode(task_id,1,task_id,2,task_id,3,task_id),3*task_time)`

Answer (score 1):

`decode ( (taskid-1)*(taskid-2)*(taskid-3), 0, 3 * tasktime  )` could do what you want

Here's a working example:

```
with a as (
  select 1 taskid, 11 tasktime from dual union all
  select 2 taskid, 11 tasktime from dual union all
  select 3 taskid, 11 tasktime from dual union all
  select 4 taskid, 11 tasktime from dual
)
select 
  taskid,
  decode (
    (taskid-1) *
    (taskid-2) *
    (taskid-3) ,
    0, 3 * tasktime 
)                                  decoded
from a;
```

Comment: Very clever, but this is the sort of workaround which was necessary back in the days of Oracle7.  The OP is on Oracle 10g and should just use CASE().

Answer (score 0):

you can use union all:

```
select 3 * task_time from your_table where task_id in (1,2,3)
union all
select task_time from your_table where task_id not in (1,2,3)
```

but why ?

Answer (score 0):

In if condition :

```
IF vVal in (3,1,2) THEN
     dbms_output.put_line('FOUND');
   ELSE
    dbms_output.put_line('NOT FOUND');
   END IF;
```

Answer (score 0):

I've seen `instr(...)` and static strings used as a way to quickly determine whether a value is one of multiple you're looking for as a condition for what value you return. You may need to choose a delimiter, but with limited datasets you can even omit it. It avoids using case-when, subqueries, and PL/SQL. As far as I know, there is no shorter way to do this:

```
decode(instr('123', taskid), 0, null, taskid * 3)
```

It's also very convenient when you want to set exceptions (for instance returning `taskid` without multiplication if it equals `1`):

```
decode(instr('12345', taskid), 0, null, 1, taskid, taskid * 3)
```